# Laravel Routing does not Controller

Tags: php, laravel

I want to access my controller and show and log the test messages.

I have been trying to access my controller via a route but it doesn't seem to work.
It's my first time using Laravel so I hope anyone can help I have been struggling with this problem for a couple of hours.

It hasn't been showing error messages, but I can't find any mistakes in my syntax I tried finding if there might be possible problems in my php.ini files, but I don't know.

the form

```
                <form method="post" action="{{ Route('saveItem') }}" accept-charset="UTF-8">
                    {{  csrf_field()  }}
                    
                    <label for="listItem">New Todo Item</label><br>
                    <input type="text" name="listItem">
                    <button type="submit">Save item</button>
                </form>
```

Route

```
Route::post('/saveItemRoute', [TodoListController::class, 'saveItem'])->name('saveItem');
```

Controller

```
class TodoListController extends Controller
{
    public function saveItem(Request $request) {
        echo("<h1>victory2</h1>");

        \Log::debug("TodoListController");
        \Log::info(json_encode($request->all()));
        
        $newListItem = new ListItem;
        $newListItem->name = $request->ListItem;
        $newListItem->is_complete = 0;
        $newListItem->save();


        return view('welcome');
    }
}
```

After trying again it seem like the rout doesnt function / do anything and i cant figure out why

Comment: `name="listItem"` vs. `$request->ListItem`? What exactly doesn't work? Form does not submit?

Comment: Unrelated fyi: the `for` attribute on a label should point to an `id` attribute on a form element.

Comment: The form does submit but and the route does seem connect since when i change it it says route not found. But the controller doesnt do anything / isnt called upon.

Comment: Thank you for the answers btw. should i provide more code? or the things that are linked to the files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know what whent wrong after changes to routing i needed to do this line in the cmd

```
    php artisan route:clear
```

the first time i tested the routing code but i did not know after changes you need to clear the route